# How to calculate operating torque and holding torque of a slew drive for a manipulator arm?

Tags: servomotor, manipulator, torque, gearing

Hope you are doing good and enjoying your weekend.
I have a question regarding calculation of torque and tilting moment for a slew drive. Slew drive (motorised) will be used at the base of a manipulator arm to facilitate the arm rotation in 360°.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxyG4.jpg).

**For tilting moment :** (**the mass of each part of manipulator arm**) * (**perpendicular distance between CG of each part and axis of rotation**) (as shown in image)

**For operating torque :** I am not quite sure how to calculate that because torque is also **mass of each part** * **perpendicular distance between CG and axis of rotation**. Then I thought that acceleration torque itself is the operating torque in my case (please correct me if I am wrong).

There is no existing slew drive on the manipulator so I have no reference point.

Could someone please guide me with the formula for calculating operating torque and holding torque for a slew drive based on the image shown?

Thank you for your valuable time and info.
Have a great sunday :)

Answer (score 0):

It really isn't an easy problem, since the answer depends on not only the masses and locations of each element, but also the velocities and accelerations you want to support.

When I looked into this problem myself I found precious few resources to learn from.  Robotics texts tend to abstract the problem away and aren't always of much practical value.

The best starting point for me was a [really ancient paper](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/41125) from 1975 by B.K.P. Horn who as then (and still is!) with the MIT AI Lab.  I ended up writing [my own primer](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358412336_CASE_STUDIES_IN_DUAL-LINK_ROBOT_ARM_DYNAMICS) based on Prof. Horn's to walk myself through solving gradually more difficult problems.  There is a really good text book out there by Rivin on [The Mechanical Design of Robots](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070529922), but it is out of print.

Sorry - Not a very concise answer to your question, but maybe a starting point.